# Mongodb group query for embeded docs

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Is it possible to query value counts for a particular key inside embeded documents.

Here is my document:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "drives" : [ {"fw": "A"}, {"fw": "B"} ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "drives" : [ {"fw": "B"}, {"fw": "C"} ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "drives" : [ {"fw": "A"}, {"fw": "C"} ] }
{ "_id" : 4, "drives" : [ {"fw": "A"}, {"fw": "D"} ] }
```

And i would like to get the count of "fw":

Output:

counts : {"A": 3, "B": 2, "C": 2, "D": 1 }

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can group the similar ones and return its count using aggregation pipelines. Specifically, $group. Give it a try. [docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/)

Comment: The JSON in the example is invalid, I assume you mean `drives` to be an array of objects, not an object of arrays?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Fixed. thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregation will do it. First [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array to get a row per `fw` value, then [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) by the value of `fw` along with a [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) of 1 to get the count per `fw` value;

```js
db.test.aggregate( { $unwind: "$drives" }, 
                   { $group: { _id: "$drives.fw", cnt: {$sum:1} } } )

# { "_id" : "D", "cnt" : 1 }
# { "_id" : "C", "cnt" : 2 }
# { "_id" : "B", "cnt" : 2 }
# { "_id" : "A", "cnt" : 3 }
```

Comment: This give the total count, is it possible to get the unique count.

Comment: if you realize your comment is not applicable, you can delete.  If the answer is correct, you should accept it.